# How to get value of check box in Nativescript?

Tags: javascript, xml, nativescript

I'm new to nativscript, i'm using nativescript-checkbox. i want to get the value from the checkbox.i have seen in git hub but i didn't find the solution to get the property. https://libraries.io/npm/nativescript-checkbox

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you please share code you have tried so far?

Comment: the link you included says it all how to get the properties of checkbox and it's quite simple. What is your problem? Could you share your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a very basic example of how to handle the checkbox from nativescript-checkbox plugin.

e.g. for TypeScript enabled project

***page.xml***

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" 
      xmlns:CheckBox="nativescript-checkbox" 
      loaded="pageLoaded">
  <StackLayout>
    <CheckBox:CheckBox text="CheckBox Label" id="myCheckbox" checked="false" />
    <Button text="on toggleCheck" tap="toggleCheck" />
    <Button text="on getCheckProp" tap="getCheckProp" /> 
  </StackLayout>
</Page>
```

***page.ts***

```
    import { EventData } from 'data/observable';
    import { Page } from 'ui/page';
    import { CheckBox } from 'nativescript-checkbox';
    import { topmost } from 'ui/frame';

    let page;

    export function pageLoaded(args: EventData) {
      page = <Page>args.object;
    }

    export function toggleCheck() {
      let checkBox = <CheckBox>page.getViewById('myCheckbox');
      checkBox.toggle();
    }

    export function getCheckProp() {
      let checkBox = <CheckBox>page.getViewById('myCheckbox');
      console.log('checked prop value = ' + checkBox.checked); // will return true of false
    }
```